# AngularJS/Ionic promises - sometimes page loads forever

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework, promise, q

I am using promises in my controller, and most of the times it works well. But sometimes it just loads forever and the `WordPress.getAllCategories()` function does not even get called.

This is my controller:
var mod = angular.module('app.controllers.home', []);

```
mod.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $q, $sce, $ionicPlatform, WordPress, Loading) {
  console.log('HomeCtrl init');

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
    Loading.show();

    WordPress.getAllCategories()
      .then(function (cats) {
        console.info(angular.toJson(cats));
        console.info('cats ^');
        $q.all(cats.data.map(function (cat) {
          var d = $q.defer();

          console.error(cat.name);

          WordPress.getLatestPostOfCategory(cat.id)
            .then(function (post) {

              console.debug(post.data.title.rendered);

              WordPress.getMediaById(post.data.featured_media)
                .then(function (media) {

                  console.log(media.data.source_url);

                  cat.firstPost = {};
                  cat.firstPost.id = post.data.id;
                  cat.firstPost.title = post.data.title.rendered;
                  cat.firstPost.content = post.data.content.rendered;

                  if (cat.firstPost.title.length > 50) {
                    cat.firstPost.title = cat.firstPost.title + '...';
                  }

                  if (cat.firstPost.content.length > 70) {
                    cat.firstPost.content = cat.firstPost.content.substr(0, 60) + '...';
                  }
                  cat.firstPost.thumbnail = media.data.source_url;
                  d.resolve(cat);
                }, function (err) {
                  console.error(angular.toJson(err));
                });
            });

          return d.promise;
        })).then(function (cats) {
          console.log('Loaded all articles and for main page.');
          $scope.homeCategories = cats;
          Loading.hide();
        });
      });
  });
});
```

Is there anything wrong in my controller?
P.S. I also debug all the WordPress service functions and they work just fine, and provide the needed data.

**EDIT:**

Sometimes when it loads forever, I see the `console.error(cat.name);` debug message only logs 3 messages. But still proceeds to the next function...

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) and all your problems will go away! (hint: you're leaving some promises in the array forever pending)

Comment: @Bergi Can you please try to give me an example? I am trying for hours...

Comment: Always `return` a promise, from *every* function that does something asynchronous. Especially `then` callbacks.

Comment: @Bergi Hey, is this better? Am I on the right way for the solution? https://jsfiddle.net/48v4f5nw/1/

Comment: Yes, that's it, I don't see anything missing. Is it working? You might want to [post it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Actually it does work. Thanks a lot @Bergi! Will do but I am not sure if I can accept my own answer.

Comment: You can accept it after 48 hours of competition :-)

Comment: @Bergi you rock :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, by Bergi's advice.

Source for help: [Promise anti pattern by Gorgi Kosev (bluebird)](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)

```
   var categories = [];

    function sort() {
      return WordPress.getAllCategories()
        .then(function (cats) {
          console.log('thens');
          return $q.all(cats.data.map(function (cat) {
            console.info('cat: ' + cat.name);

            var category = {};
            category.name = cat.name;

            return WordPress.getLatestPostOfCategory(cat.id)
              .then(function (post) {

                var post = post.data;
                category.post = {};
                category.post.id = post.id;
                category.post.title = post.title.rendered;
                category.post.content = post.content.rendered;

                console.log('ID: ' + category.post.id + ', title: ' + category.post.title);

                return WordPress.getMediaById(post.featured_media);
              }).then(function (media) {
                category.post.thumbnail = media.data.source_url;

                categories.push(category);
                console.log('Pushed category "' + category.name + '"');
              });
          }));
        }, function (err) {
          console.error('ERR1');
          console.error(angular.toJson(err));
        });
    }

    sort()
      .then(function () {
        console.info('LOADED ALL CATEGORIES');
        $scope.categories = categories;
      }, function (err) {
        console.error('err:' + angular.toJson(err));
      });
```